# R caret / gbm code won't predict : dim(X) must have a positive length

Tags: r, r-caret, gbm

I'm trying to use caret to find the best parameters for a gbm model.  This code is identical to what I've used on other data sets and can't figure out the error.

It seems to run the model but can't create predictions.

```
predictions failed for Fold2: interaction.depth=4, shrinkage=0.005, n.trees=200 Error in apply(tmp, 2, function(x, nm = modelFit$obsLevels) ifelse(x >=  : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

Here's the full code:

```
library(caret)
library(gbm)

myControl <- trainControl(method='cv', number=2, summaryFunction=twoClassSummary,
                          classProbs=TRUE, savePredictions=TRUE, verboseIter=TRUE)


df1 <- data.frame(Y = round(runif(1000), 0), x1=runif(1000), x2=runif(1000) )

X <- df1[,c('x1','x2')]
Y <- factor(paste('X', df1[,'Y']))


gbm_model <- train(X, Y, method='gbm', metric='ROC', trControl=myControl 
                   ,distribution='bernoulli', tuneGrid=expand.grid(.n.trees=seq(100, 200, by=100) 
                   ,.interaction.depth=seq(2, 4, by=2), .shrinkage=c(.005)))
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I'm using `gbm 2.1` and `caret 5.16.24`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a bug. I had a new version of caret to submit today but I'll make these changes prior to sending it in.

There is a little disconnect between your code and output. I get an additional warning: "At least one of the class levels are not valid R variables names; This may cause errors if class probabilities are generated because the variables names will be converted to: X.0, X.1". Add a `sep = ""` in the `paste` command and it goes away.

Max

Answer (score 3):

You might also get this error if you try to run a caret model and mistakenly just included a dependent variable with only one factor in it.

Comment: Or if you mistakenly included a factor with only 1 level in it.